# Im trying to create a local database in swift that will pass data to elements in a viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, database

What is the best way to create a local databas I swift and fetch data from it when an IBAction is tapped. Lets say I want to make a recipe app and when I click on "Food1" an IBAction with a unique key I sent to the database and it will populate the "RecipeDetailView" from the databas.

Im note sure on which way to go. Should I use a thridparty database manger like Realm or can I just create the whole databas in Swift.

The database should contain stuff like a local image, title, description etc. And I want to connect the data to labels, textviews and image view.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing seems like you want to work with Core Data, Apple's built in persistence framework. For more information look at the [Core Data programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/index.html)
There are loads of tutorials and books about Core Data. Look at the [Getting Started with Core Data Tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/7569-getting-started-with-core-data-tutorial) on raywenderlich.com